# Simulating 'git pull' for an "air gapped" system by transferring git changesets as a tarball

Tags: git

I need to sync git repos to an "air gapped" system creating a mirror environment on the system. Files must be transferred through a special approved channel. New code also has to go through a lengthy review and approval process before being allowed onto the system.

The code develops quickly and I want to do weekly syncs of particular branches - as if I were just executing a git pull. Re-transferring the entire git repo is not really an option. It would be much easier to clear our review and approval to review just code diffs.

Is there a way using bundle or archive or diff-tree or something similar to dump just the new changesets into a file and do a git pull/fetch from that file on the air gapped system to update the repos?

I've looked through documentation on patches, archives, diff trees, and previous answers, but I don't think any of this provides exactly what I need.

Comment: What exactly can you do on the air-gapped system? Can you run git commands that don't need network access? Or are you only allowed to add/remove/replace files in a given directory?

Comment: You *can* simply run `git pull`: copy the entire repository (using a usb stick, etc) into a new location on your air-gapped host, then `git add remote origin /path/to/copy`, then run `git pull`.

Comment: @muru: We can run git commands. The idea is basically to mirror a necessary subset of Github so people can continue their workflow as if they still had github access.

Comment: @larsks: File transfer approval might require reviewing the entire repo again. Everything goes faster if only the new changesets need to be reviewed. The bundling of individual changesets goes both ways, actually. Everything going on or off has to be approved. Download approval is probably more important than upload, actually, moving code fixes off the system.

Answer (score 8):

Git does not work with, nor store, diffs.  Git works with, and stores, commits (which in turn store trees and blobs) and tags (which generally tag commits, which store trees and blobs).

That said, `git bundle` **is** the command you're looking for: it's essentially the server side half of `git fetch` and its output is a file that `git fetch` on the client side can read.  So you treat the machine that produces the bundle as if it were a server: you tell it what commits the client already has, and what branch name(s) you think the client should see when it receives the fetch that the client has not yet actually run.  The server (building the bundle) then packages up the same data that `git fetch` would get, if that later `git fetch` could actually reach the server.

You then hand-carry the data (e.g., on a USB stick) to the client, plug it into the client, and, on the client, run `git fetch` on the data file that, as far as the client is concerned, it's now, in real-time, retrieving over the wire from the server located inside the file (e.g., inside the USB stick).

The one big hitch is that since the USB stick (or whatever it is) *isn't* really a server, and the client therefore is not actually talking to the server live, you have to have gotten the `git bundle` command right on the server.  If you missed any commits, the fetch will fail.  If you included too many commits, the fetch will succeed, so to "get it right" you can start by bundling the entire repository, or some particular set of branches, then save markers on the sending side to remember what you have bundled.  Hence the example in [the `git bundle` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-bundle):

```
machineA$ cd R1
machineA$ git bundle create file.bundle master
machineA$ git tag -f lastR2bundle master
```

You now transfer `file.bundle` to the "client" and can clone from that file.

Later, after `machineA` has new commits, you can run:

```
machineA$ cd R1
machineA$ git bundle create file.bundle lastR2bundle..master
machineA$ git tag -f lastR2bundle master
```

to (a) send new commits to the client and (b) update your server-side memory of what commits you sent to the client.  (The actual sending, of course, takes place later, via USB stick or whatever.)

This marker is really just any arbitrary commit hash ID, or a name that serves as one, or something else to establish the "basis commit(s)" that the server will assume that the client already has.

(Note that the bundle contains a "thin pack", i.e., objects delta-compressed against objects that the server believes the client has.  The client will fatten the thin pack as needed, since Git doesn't like depending on this kind of delta-compression—thin packs are only allowed during the network connection, including the faked-up one with this sort of air-gap.  An empty basis means that the pack isn't thin after all, but rather is the entire repository.)