# Synchronize two Git repositories without direct connection

Tags: git

I have two git repositories which I need to synchronize without having direct network connection between them.

I cannot use `git fetch` or `git push` as-is because both of them require that direct connection. Patchfiles also don't seem to be a viable option because they lose commit tree structure. Although, I've discovered that git uses `git pack-objects` and `git unpack-objects` under the hood to generate and consume pack-files.

Can I somehow make Git generate that packfile for me (given I provide commit range I want) and then consume it? Or maybe there's some way to preserve structure in patches? Or maybe there's some other approach?

Thanks

Comment: use a (bare, probably) repo on a usb and share it between the computers.

Comment: Already answered in comments to https://stackoverflow.com/a/55971673/508023. ~500km distance.

Comment: Please *read* initial question. Anyway, https://stackoverflow.com/a/55971126/508023 is precisely what I needed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Synchronizing git repositories without access to each other and no access to both from any system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55616223/synchronizing-git-repositories-without-access-to-each-other-and-no-access-to-bot)

Comment: Other duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/55567263/947357

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try [git bundle](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-bundle).

A bundle works as a read-only repository. To create a bundle of the branch `master`,

```
git bundle create foo.bundle master
```

Then you can move `foo.bundle` to the machine where the other repository is and read/fetch the metadata you need.

```
cd <the_other_repository>
git checkout master
git pull <path_to_foo.bundle> master

# or maybe you want to cherry-pick a single commit
git fetch <path_to_foo.bundle> master
git cherry-pick <commit>
```

Comment: Looks really promising. Will try and report later.

Comment: Thanks! that's definitely the solution I've been looking for.

Comment: If you want to *clone* a new repository from a bundle, you need to include "HEAD" as one of the branches in the bundle.